# No me trae el id por método GET y me devuelve un null

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, php7

en este primer codigo muestro las publicaciones un usuario

```html
<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->

<!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
<section class="content-header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row mb-2">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h1>Perfil</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h5>Mis publicaciones</h5>
        
        
        <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
          <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="perfil-enterprise">Perfil</a></li>
          <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Mis publicaciones</li>
        </ol>
        <a class="btn btn-primary float-right" href="publicar-trabajo" style="margin-right: 15px;">Publicar un Trabajo</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</section>

<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content ">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">

        <!-- Profile Image -->
        <div class="card card-primary card-outline">
          <div class="card-body box-profile">
            <div class="text-center">
              <img  style="display:none;" class="profile-user-img img-fluid img-circle"
                  
                   
               
        
        
        class="user-image" alt="User Image">
        <label>COVID-19
</label>
        
    
            
                
                
            
            </div>

           
            
            
 
            
            
         

 
            <ul class="list-group list-group-unbordered mb-3">
              <li class="list-group-item">
                <b>Otras empresas se están conectando con expertos para adaptarse en estos tiempos inciertos. Elija un talento y protéjase.</b>
              </li>
            
             
            </ul>

         
          </div>
          <!-- /.card-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->

        
        <!-- /.card -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.col -->
      <div class="col-md-9">
       
       
       
                       
            
                      <?php
                $conn=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bdtrabajo","root","");
$id =$_SESSION['id'];


      
            

$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM publicaciones where idusuario='$id'";
            
            $resultadoM = $conn->query($sql3);
 while($row=$resultadoM->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
           
              
            {
            ?>
       
     
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header p-2">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
             
    <li class="nav-item"><h5 class="nav-link"  ><i class="far fa-file-alt mr-1"></i>
             <a href="publicacion?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["titulo"]; ?></a>
             </h5></li>
              
              
              
            </ul>
            
            <!--
            
            <button class="btneditardescrip" idusuario="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditarDescrip" style="border-radius:15px;
 outline:none; background:none; border:1px solid #C1C7CA; float:right;">  <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button> 
 <button class="btnimprimircurriculum" codigocurriculum="" data-toggle="modal"  style="border-radius:15px;
 outline:none; background:none; border:1px solid #C1C7CA; float:right;">  <i class="fas fa-print"></i></button>
    -->
    
         
         
          </div><!-- /.card-header -->
     
             
   
             
             
             
              <!-- /.tab-pane -->
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="active tab-pane" id="emp">
               
               
               
                    
               
               
                <label>Fecha de publicación:</label><?php echo $row["fecha_publicacion"]; ?><br>
                
                <label>Descripción:</label><?php echo $row["descripciontrabajo"]; ?>
                
                
              </div>
              <!-- /.tab-pane -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.tab-content -->
          </div><!-- /.card-body -->
        </div>
        
                 <?php
            }
                
                
            ?> 
           
        
        
       
        
      </div>
      <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</section>
<!-- /.content -->
```

por medio de un enlace envio la variable del id y quiero llamarlo mediante metodo GET a esa variable para luego mostrar todos los campos que tiene esa publicacion
pero por algun motivo solo me manda a una pagina en blanco y si pongo var_dump de la variable me bota null alguien sabe que sucede o que error estoy cometiendo se los agradeceria demasiado

```html
  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->

    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1>Perfil</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h5>Mis publicaciones</h5>
            
            
            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="perfil-enterprise">Perfil</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Mis publicaciones</li>
            </ol>
            <a class="btn btn-primary float-right" href="publicar-trabajo" style="margin-right: 15px;">Publicar un Trabajo</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">

            <!-- Profile Image -->
            <div class="card card-primary card-outline">
              <div class="card-body box-profile">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <img  style="display:none;" class="profile-user-img img-fluid img-circle"
                      
                       
                   
            
            
            class="user-image" alt="User Image">
            <label>COVID-19
</label>
            
        
                
                    
                    
                
                </div>

               

            
                
             

     
                <ul class="list-group list-group-unbordered mb-3">
                  <li class="list-group-item">
                    <b>Otras empresas se están conectando con expertos para adaptarse en estos tiempos inciertos. Elija un talento y protéjase.</b>
                  </li>
                
                 
                </ul>

             
              </div>
              <!-- /.card-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->

            
            <!-- /.card -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-md-9">
           
           
           
                           
                
               
<?php
         
         
         $conn=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bdtrabajo","root","");
        
             
              $idpublicacion=@$_GET["id"];

    
              
              var_dump($idpublicacion);
              
              echo $idpublicacion;
       $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM publicaciones where id='$idpublicacion'";
              
              
                    $resultadoM = $conn->query($sql3);
 while($row=$resultadoM->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
               
                  
                {
              
              
      
                       
?>  
           
         
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header p-2">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                 
                  <li class="nav-item"><h5 class="nav-link"  ><i class="far fa-file-alt mr-1"></i></h5></li>
                  
                  
                  
                </ul>
                
                
                
                
        
        
             
             
              </div><!-- /.card-header -->
         
                 
   
                 
                 
                 
                  <!-- /.tab-pane -->
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="tab-content">
                  <div class="active tab-pane" id="emp">
                   
                   
                   
                        
                   
                   
                    <label>Fecha de publicación:</label><?php echo $row["fecha_publicacion"]; ?><br>
                    
                    <label>Descripción:</label><?php echo $row["descripciontrabajo"]; ?>
                    
                    
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.tab-pane -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.tab-content -->
              </div><!-- /.card-body -->
            </div>
            
         
    <?php
                }
                ?>
    
               
            
            
           
            
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
```

COLOCO EL CODIGO QUE USO PARA LAS URL AMIGABLE

```html
     
    if(isset($_GET["ruta"])){
        
       if($_GET["ruta"]=="inicio" ||  $_GET["ruta"]=="logout" || $_GET["ruta"]=="inicio"  ||  $_GET["ruta"]=="complete-perfil" ||  $_GET["ruta"]=="perfil"  ||  $_GET["ruta"]=="reporte" ||  $_GET["ruta"]=="complete-enterprise"  ||  $_GET["ruta"]=="perfil-enterprise"   ||  $_GET["ruta"]=="publicar-trabajo" ||  $_GET["ruta"]=="mis-publicaciones" ||  $_GET["ruta"]=="publicacion"){
            include "modules/".$_GET["ruta"].".php";

        }
        else{
            include"modules/404.php";
        }
    }
    else{
         include"modules/inicio.php";
    }
```

Comment: No veo el enlace donde tengan el get para esa pagina, de donde llega ese get a tu pagina??

Comment: Gracias amigo por responderme , en el el primero codigo justo dentro del card <a href="publicacion?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">  y mi pagina que lo recibe es todo el segundo codigo publicacion.php

Comment: Y tienes algun .htaccess que te lee esa ruta de 'publicacion?id=' porque deberia de ser 'publicacion.php?id=' ??

Comment: en la linea 107, si no me equivoco tienes mal puestas las comillas: <a href="publicacion?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["titulo"]; ?></a>

Comment: Si amigo gerardo estoy usando url amigables  htaccess , eso estaria creando problemas? soy un poco nuevo

Comment: amigo israel acabo de revisar esa linea y no veo un error al menos que no me haya dado cuenta de algún detalle si me podrías especificar por favor amigo te lo agradecería.

Comment: @cristhiandg cuando le das click al enlace con el _get te lleva a segunda pagina donde tiene la llamada del get?? y en la URL ves el valor enviado???

Comment: Asi es me sale en la barra de direcciones esto: http://localhost:8080/trabajo2/publicacion?id=99 tambien en mi pagina publicacion puse esto pero no me bota ningun resultado  $idpublicacion = $_GET['id'];

    
     echo "El identificador de esta publicacion es: $idpublicacion";

Comment: Habia publicado una respuesta pero veo que le comentas a @GerardoMarroquin que usas .htaccess, podrías agregar como redireccionas la url de publicacion ?

Comment: @Israel que agrege el htacces que tiene, puede que el htaccess este bloqueando ella forma de como llamar el get, porque supongo que si tiene ese tipo de rutas esta utilizando las url amigables

Comment: COLOCARE EN LA PUBLICACION LO QUE ESTOY UTILIZANDO PARA REDIRECCIONAR MUCHAS GRACIAS AMIGOS POR QUERER GUIARME EN ESTO

Comment: @cristhiandg pon tambien tu .htaccess porque ahi es donde puede estar tu problema

Comment: esta bien amigo

Comment: @GerardoMarroquin Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?ruta=$1

Comment: Que tal amigos gracias por ayudarme logre descubrir y el problema estaba al final de mi linea de .htaccess y es que me falta poner el parámetro --> [QSA] que lo que investigando encontré que sirve para  --> El parametro [QSA] si no me equivoco, permite añadir a la url parámetros GET en la url. dejando el codigo asi  : Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?ruta=$1 [QSA]